# Two sided paper scans with Epson WorkForce ES-400

Tags: scanner

Below is a video of a paper scanner, that scans paper that has print on both sides.  See the very beginning of the video.  However, I am unable to figure out how to scan both sides of the paper using the scanner buttons themselves.  Does anyone know if this is controlled by the hardware or the software?  If so, how can this be done?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9aPTMRChNw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [manual](https://files.support.epson.com/docid/cpd5/cpd51578.pdf), page 54 and onwards, you can assign a custom configuration to the scan button. There is a caveat in the manual that says you cannot scan via wireless using the button, but that's not a factor in your question.

```
    Assigning Start Button Settings or Scan Jobs
You can view or change the default scan settings when you scan using
the start button on your scanner.
You do this by accessing the scan jobs in the Document Capture Pro (Windows)
or Document Capture (OS X) program.
```

The manual does not provide a screen shot of the page that would allow you to specify double sides, in the pp 54-55 region, but does show such a page elsewhere in the manual.

It is typical for scanner software to allow custom configuration of various buttons on the device. Mediocre software often omits such features.

Comment: Nice, +1.  Instead of using the scan button on the hardware/scanner itself, I clicked the "Scan" button in the software called Espon Scan 2, per page 58 in the manual, without changing any settings.  The "Scanning Side" field was already set to "Double-Sided".  I'll have to update the default scan settings once I find out where to get Document Capture Pro.  Thanks!!

Comment: After countless tries at this, now I figured out why Espon chose to use the software to handle this functionality, and not the hardware buttons to handle this functionality.  There is a bug.  If you have the speed button enabled to fast (button on scanner with icon containing two parallel horizontal lines on top of each other, with a third horizontal right arrow above those lines), meaning it's lit up with a blue light with no other configuration toggle buttons enabled (lit up to blue), this feature works great!

Comment: If you have any other configuration, you'll get a paper jam error with the Epson Scan 2 software during every scan.

Comment: Error: "A paper jam or double feed has occurred.  See the documentation for instructions on removing the originals.  Click [Continue] to resume scanning.  Click [Save and Exit] to save scanned pages and go to the main menu.  Click [Stop] to stop scanning and discard scanned pages."

Comment: You have to re-enabled that toggle button on every scan if using this double-sided feature, because it turns off after each scan of a set of paper in the paper feeder.